# Does anyone know the correct path to access the xml-files, images,... from OLAT or how to use/access files between 2 servers

Tags: java, php, networking

As the title says, I would like to know where or how you can access files from a Course or Test in OLAT. (or maybe copy them)

at this moment, we  have a server where OLAT is installed on and we have also another server with PHP. Those 2 servers are seperated and aren't directly wired connected with each other.

The trickiest thing is that, this is at an university and security is top priority.

The path that we use now is eg. /opt/olat/olatdata/bcroot/course ... 
Of course this will only work when everything is in the same location.

---

I was wondering of that you could rebuild the `hash` but dont know how to begin on that

```
(http://192.168.56.101:8080/OLAT-LMS-7.2.1.0/m/**aad7874b6b41278d91852c80eb5156cb**/Campin_Madonna.jpg)
```

**More info:**
The reason for this all is
the professors of the university have made a lot of excercises and courses in OLAT.
But there are too less features  in OLAT so they want a php application where they can have some drag and drop excercise or other stuff. Now we need use a php server that uses the information (xml, pdf's, images, include html pages) from the OLAT server because everyday there could be build new courses in OLAT (or changes) and it would be usefull if the php application doesn't have any troubles with that.

any other suggestions are welcome

Kind regards

Dieter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, security is a top prio, thus it is not possible to use those fancy URL's to retrieve the images from another application as they are only valid when the user is logged in and is in the right location. E.g. images from a secific test can only be viewed when the test is actually running for this user.

The hash itself is simple, it is an md5 hash of the file system path. Have a look at MapperRegistry.registerCacheable().

A better solution would be to use the REST API. But as I heard UZH will drop support for that. Maybe you should also have a look at the free alternative OpenOLAT that has a much greater feature set compared to OLAT: http://www.openolat.org

Cheers
Florian